# How can i change hover in drop down menu in my bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```css
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open.active > a:hover, 
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open > a
{
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #f7ad1a;
   border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="ediwow actives"><a href="index1.php"><b>Home</b></a></li>
    <li class="dropdown ediwow" role="presentation">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b style="color:white;">Room</b>
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#537e9e;">
     <li><a href="#">Function Room</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Plenary Hall</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="ediwow"><a href="contact.php"><b>Contact</b></a></li>
    <li class="ediwow"><a href="about.php"><b>About us</b></a></li>
    <li class="ediwow"><a href="location.php"><b>Location</b></a></li>
    <div class="dropdown" style="float:right; margin-top:12px; margin-left:500px;">
     <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) 
    {
     echo '<b style="color:wiht;">Welcome</b> <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">'. $_SESSION["fname"] . '<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu ediwow" style="background-color:#537e9e;">
         <li><a href="changeoass_form.php">Change Password</a></li>
         <li><a href="singout.php">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>';
    } 
    else 
    {
     echo '<li><a href="singin.php" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:15px; color:white;">Sign in | Sign up</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Hi guys im a beginner in making a web for now im using bootstrap for my design 
my problem in i don`t know how to change hover color in drop down menu in bootstrap thx for you answer :D 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: black;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: none;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/orp8emcx/)

Comment: Sorry Reviteja im using a ul li drop down menu

Comment: could you please add your css and html to your question ?